# Find connection from specific port number connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, port, sqlconnection

I have a requirement to find if any traffic is hitting my SQL Server on a specific port number 8082. If not, I will block that port.

The problem is I am not able to identify any way to check if any traffic from that port number is sent to my SQL Server.

Please if anyone can suggest a way how to identify traffic coming from a specific port number in SQL Server.

I have tried using profiler but there is no such counter which shows port number of connections.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about source port numbers. It varies from operating system to operating system, but generally (TCP) port numbers above 1024 are assigned either randomly or sequentially when opening new outgoing connections. So, yes, there's always a chance that incoming traffic to tcp/1433 (the destination port) could be coming from a client on tcp/8082 (the source port). e.g.: Older Windows assigned their ephemeral (dynamic) ports from 1025-5000, newer ones from 49152-65535, but this is fully configurable using `netsh` on Windows 10 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does have a DMV which may be of use to you:

```
SELECT Session_ID, most_recent_session_id, connect_time, client_net_address, client_tcp_port, local_net_address, local_tcp_port
  FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

The documentation for it can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16